# Avoid the map ending on anti-meridian in OpenLayer's OSM?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

> *I hope you help me work out the question itself. I'll do my best to get on with any comment and suggestion you make to improve it.*

I have a map using OpenLayers with the OSM maps, for which the configs I'm still trying to understand. I *feel* it **must** be an option to avoid the map "ending" at the right of the 180º meridian, and *repeat* the west map there instead of showing this grey area:

[image: My flat-with-a-turtle-below view of the world]

I know that's possible because, for example, the tiny example on the [OpenLayers website](http://openlayers.org/) shows it OK (ie, the world *is* "circular" there), but it doesn't seem to have any special flag to enable this:

[image: A more actual point of view]

So my guess is that anywhere on the whole codebase someone disabled it at any moment, but I don't even know what to start looking for.

Is there any flag that enables/disables this behaviour? What may my code be doing to negate the idea of a spherical Earth on this view?

Some (i hope) relevant bits of code - but there are tens of lines in the middle, so please help me identify what else could be relevant:

```js
self.projection = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
self.displayProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');

var zoombar = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(
    {'div': OpenLayers.Util.getElement('map-controls')}
);

var ol_options = {
    controls: [
        zoombar,
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
    ],
    projection: self.projection,
    displayProjection: self.displayProjection,
    units: 'm',
    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
    panDuration: 20
};


self.map = new OpenLayers.Map(div, ol_options); // div is a function parameter

self.osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
  "Open Street Map",
  "",
  {zoomOffset: 8, resolutions: [611.496226171875, 305.7481130859375, 152.87405654296876, 76.43702827148438, 38.21851413574219, 19.109257067871095, 9.554628533935547, 4.777314266967774, 2.388657133483887,1.1943285667419434, 0.597164283]}
);

self.map.addLayers([self.osmLayer]);
```

Comment: Is this OpenLayers 3 or OpenLayers 2? Your link goes to 3, but this has not been officially released yet. The two code bases are very different, so this is relevant.

Comment: @JohnBarça Thanks for pointing it out. It's OpenLayers 2. I didn't know about the difference...

Comment: No worries. In that case could you provide a bit of code to show how you got the above view. Usually, extents and resolutions, passed as options to map constructor, determine how it looks, but impossible to tell from your question as it stands.

Comment: Por lo que vale, tu blog es muy gracioso.

Comment: @JohnBarça but is this accomplishable in OpenLayers 2? The problem is that the codebase is really huge, and I don't sort of know where to start. I'll try to add some bits of _maybe_ relevant code, anyway.